# Re-partition Hyper-V Server Virtual Hard Drive (VHD) with Windows Server 2003 installed

Tags: windows-server-2003, partition, hyper-v-server-2008-r2, vhd

can anyone recommend a re-partitioning tool to resize the primary partition of a VHD that I’ve just expanded by a couple of GB which has windows server 2003 32bit standard installed. I'm using Windows Hyper-V Server 2008 R2 as the host.

edit:
the partition is a system partition

Comment: I don't have a third party recommendation, but here's a thread from social.technet.com that suggests connecting the volume to a Server 2008 VM and expanding it there, then reconnecting it to a 2003 VM. It's something I plan to try with a recent P2V: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winserverhyperv/thread/d0912ef9-be5b-44c0-962e-1740190f0376

Answer (score 2):

For a third party app. I prefer using Acronis' Disk Director: http://www.acronis.com/enterprise/products/diskdirector-server/